# How to define the type profile for this function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ml

I have to define the type profile of this function:

```
twice f x = f (f x);
```

The result should be the following, but I don't really get why.

```
('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
```

Comment: You're using a high order function, or a GoF in mathematics. Type :t to see the type. Refer to the book - learn you a Haskell

Comment: I have to define it by myself, without typing anything.

Comment: I've seen some recent SO questions using semi-colons at the end of Haskell "statements". What book / learning resource did you pick that up from, because it is not needed and not typical Haskell.

Comment: @ErikR I think this is ML, not Haskell. Note also the single-quote prefixes on the type variables.

Comment: @DanielWagner, aren't semicolons separators in ML, rather than terminators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(a -> a) -> a -> a` is the right answer. Let's split it to pieces to find out why.

1. your function takes two arguments, `f` and `x`, so the signature will have three parts - say, `a -> c -> d`
2. first of these arguments is an unary function - that makes `a = (a -> b)` (remember that `a` can be any type, as long as it appears only once in the signature) and the signature look like `(a -> b) -> c -> d`
3. result of `twice` is same as the result of its first argument - that makes `d = b` and the signature `(a -> b) -> c -> b`
4. `f` takes second argument of `twice` as its argument - this makes `c = a` and the signature look like this: `(a -> b) -> a -> b`
5. `twice` is applied to its own output, which means that `a = b` - this makes the final signature `(a -> a) -> a -> a`

Comment: Thanks for the clear explantion, I understood it! :)