# How to define the type profile for the following function?

Tags: functional-programming, ml

I have to define the type profile of this function:

```
compose(f, g, x) = f(g(x))
```

The result should be the following, but I don't really get why.

```
(’a -> ’b) * (’c -> ’a) * ’c -> ’b
```

Comment: Is this Haskell or ML? Please choose one.

Comment: What parts of that signature *do* you understand? Did you expect something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `compose`'s definition, you first apply `g` (`(’c -> ’a)`) to x, so you go from a `'c` to an `'a`. `f` (`(’a -> ’b)`) then gets applied to said `'a` and returns a `'b`, hence the overall `compose` function goes from `'c` to `'b`.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning goes pretty much the same as in your other question: [How to define the type profile for this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210584/how-to-define-the-type-profile-for-this-function/39210750#39210750)

1. 3 arguments - signature `a -> c -> e -> f`
2. first two are unary functions (`a = a -> b` and `c = c -> d`) - signature `(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> e -> f`
3. third is argument to second function (`e = c`) - signature `(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> c -> f)`
4. result of second function is argument to first one (`d = a`) - signature `(a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> f`
5. output of first function is output of whole expression (`f = b`) - signature `(a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b`

please try to provide some part of this reasoning on your own next time

EDIT: the above reasoning was the end for Haskell (with which the question was tagged in the beginning), for ML there is one more step:

6. First three are tuple argument, thus `*` between them instead of `->`, and the signature becomes `(a -> b) * (c -> a) * c -> b`